# IgniteJdbcThinDriver is not supporting transactional mode

Tags: ignite

We are planning to use the Apache Ignite inmemory database as a replacement for the RDBMS that we are currently using.

I am using the IgniteJdbcThinDriver to query/modify data on the database. Though the queries are executed within a transaction scope , they are actually getting executed in the atomic mode and hence the rollbacks are not working. 
Found out from the documentation that this was a known issue and that the feature would be available in v2.5.  So I tried with the latest Ignite version (v 2.5) but that didn't work either.

Since the  documentation mentions that the Ignite inmemory database is transactional, is there any fix or some other solution to the issue that we can implement  to achieve this, using Ignite ? This feature is crucial for us and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This feature is still in beta and release is delayed because of it's complexity. It should be included in 2.6 [IGNITE-3478](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3478)